# IOS decline incoming call programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Is there any way decline a incoming call programmatically in swift. My code like this:

```
self.callCenter.callEventHandler = {(_ call: CTCall) -> Void in
            if call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected {
                print("Call has been disconnected")
            }
            else if call.callState == CTCallStateConnected {
                print("Call has just been connected")
            }
            else if call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming {
                print("Call is incoming")
                }
            else {
                print("None of the conditions")
            }
```

I am detect incoming call state this way. But i don't know how can i change `callstate` of `CTCAll` . Please help me !.

Comment: There's no way you can do this. At least for non-jailbroken devices.

Comment: There is an objective-c code here :

Comment: This code tells you whether phone is on call or not. It doesn't allow you to modify the status. Imagine what would happen if Apple allowed apps to do that, people would create malicious apps to basically paralyze the phone by disconnecting the calls. (Always assuming that such apps would get past Apple Review and App Process watch dog will allow them to run in background for infinity time). Answer is **NO** and for Good reason!

Comment: @NSNoob just because you can't provide a good reason doesn't mean there isn't one. What about a Home Automation app that wishes to provide Caller ID and the ability to answer/decline the call based on something they did? Perhaps for disabled/blind people that have a difficult time navigating a touch interface that uses two big buttons on their night stand. When answering a technical question, it's best to keep opinionated comments/answers to yourself.

Comment: In addition to that, nearly every other system modification has a popup that asks the user and provides descriptive detail what they would use said privilege for. Notifications, Camera, GPS, all use said interface. That could easily be extended to the CallKit API.

Comment: @LeviRoberts Uh, what are you on about?  iOS (non-Jailbreak) doesn't allow an app to change the status of the call. That's not an opinion, it's a fact. Only way you can do it is via private APIs which will make your app rejected by the App Store.  That's a technical answer which perhaps requires technical background in the field. Apple already provides support for disabled people, the Automation app you describe won't get pass the review process. As for your "proposed solution", go ahead, I'll be happy to see working code by "CallKit API" capability enabled.

Comment: @LeviRoberts [This is the list of all the available capabilities btw](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/) ;) Let me know when you are done. Why if you get it done, that calls for a bounty ;)

Comment: You're completely missing my point. Just because Apple says it isn't a good idea doesn't make that as a fact either. Apple slowly implements industry standards as it see's fit because it thinks it knows best. Might I add, they constantly borrow (steal?) ideas from the Jailbreak community. Heck, some of the most notable features were available on Jailbroken phones long before Apple implemented them.

Comment: P.S. Whilst this may not currently work with the existing CallKit API, it can easily be done with a Bluetooth (software even) accessory. I used the handicapped example as just that, an example. There are other uses for this too. Like universal remotes such as Neeo. You could pause A/V equipment, display the caller ID and provide an answer/reject button without ever leaving the comfort of your couch. Ya know, just in case your phone was across the room, or house even.

Comment: @NSNoob  which private APIs can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

@interface MMCallNotificationManager()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CTCallCenter *callCenter;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL callWasStarted;
@end

@implementation MMCallNotificationManager

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
        self.callWasStarted = NO;

        __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;

        [self.callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call) {

            if ([[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateIncoming] ||
                [[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateDialing]) {

                if (weakSelf.callWasStarted == NO) {

                    weakSelf.callWasStarted = YES;

                    NSLog(@"Call was started.");
                }

            } else if ([[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateDisconnected]) {

                if (weakSelf.callWasStarted == YES)
                {
                    weakSelf.callWasStarted = NO;

                    NSLog(@"Call was ended.");
                }
            }
        }];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: This doesn't modify call state at all.

Comment: Again, this just tells you whether phone is on call or not. It doesn't let you disconnect the call

Comment: well is there any way resume application while incoming call. I'm trying to make a video call app. I want the connection not to be disconnected while incoming call.

Comment: @apache Leave that to the user. iOS lets you handle the interruptions using these status. If user doesn't want the video call to be disrupted, he will hang up on the cellular call. If he wants to take the cellular call, your app shouldn't be able to disconnect that